# Uniswap fork: addLiquidity VM Revert error

Tags: solidity, remix, uniswap, defi

I'm trying to fork uniswap in Remix, and I did those steps until now:

1. Deployed core contract - uniswap factory
2. Deployed WETH contract (got the code from WETH contract on https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xc778417e063141139fce010982780140aa0cd5ab#code)
3. Before moving to periphery got the init code from UniswapV2Pair.sol(in uniswap core repo). For that, compiled it and copied the byte code and used https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/keccak_256.html to get the init code. Changed the init code in UniswapV2Library in periphery with new value.
4. Deployed UniswapV2Router02.sol with my factory and weth addresses
5. Deployed 2 ERC20 tokens (tokenA and tokenB)
6. Approved the Router address to spend all the token balance in both tokens
7. Trying to call addLiquidity in Router and getting this error:
   [image: AddLiquidity error]

Can anybody help me? What am I missing here?

EDIT:

I just ran debug and found out that the Revert occurs inside UniswapV2Library (periphery) at getReserves() function:

```
    // fetches and sorts the reserves for a pair
    function getReserves(address factory, address tokenA, address tokenB) internal view returns (uint reserveA, uint reserveB) {
        (address token0,) = sortTokens(tokenA, tokenB);
        (uint reserve0, uint reserve1,) = IUniswapV2Pair(pairFor(factory, tokenA, tokenB)).getReserves();
        (reserveA, reserveB) = tokenA == token0 ? (reserve0, reserve1) : (reserve1, reserve0);
    }
```

The Revert occurs on the second line of this function, to be more precise.

Comment: I'm also facing the same, can you tell me how did you solve it?

Comment: Similar question https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/109628/uniswap-fork-addliquidity-vm-revert-error/135876#135876